# Norton Internet Security on my Windows 7 system is blocking xxd

Tags: windows-7, vim, norton-internet-security, xxd

`xdd` is part of Vim, and Norton seems to be blocking it on my Windows 7 computer. How do I work around this? Should I be concerned?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I work around this?

You can whitelist `xxd`:

> **Exclude files or folders from scan**
>
> - If you are certain that the file is good, then you can exclude the files or folders from being scanned.
> - Start your Norton product.
> - Click Settings.
> - Under Detailed Settings, click Antivirus.
> - On the Scans and Risks tab, scroll down to Exclusions / Low Risks.
> - Next to Items to Exclude from Auto-Protect, SONAR and Download Intelligence Detection row, click Configure.
> - In the Real Time Exclusions window, click Add Folders or Add Files.
> - Browse for and select the folders or files that you want to exclude from the scan, and then click OK.
> - Click Apply, and then click OK.

Source [NIS 2017- How to Whitelist... a program?](https://community.norton.com/en/forums/nis-2017-how-whitelist-program)

---

#### Should I be concerned?

If the program is genuine and downloaded from a reputable site then no

If you downloaded it from some random internet site then yes.

In any case you can submit it to https://www.virustotal.com/ which will:

> Analyze suspicious files and URLs to detect types of malware including viruses, worms, and trojans.